# Python regex with slash

Tags: python, regex

Why does

```
len(re.findall('[0-9999][/][0-9999]', '15/11/2012'))
```

correctly return 2, but

```
len(re.findall('[0-9999][/][0-9999][/]', '15/11/2012'))
```

return 0? Shouldn’t it return 1?

Answer (score 8):

You're misunderstanding character classes. The expression, `[abc123]` matches a *single* character—namely one of the characters in the bracket. The `-` is a *range operator* in character classes, but regular expressions are not aware of *numeric* ranges, only *string* ranges. In other words, `[0-9999]` is equivalent to `[0-9]`, you're just specifying the `9` duplicate times.

The reason you find 2 matches with the first regex is that you're matching `5/1` and `1/2`. The second regex doesn't have the flexibility of matching any one-digit number, and thus fails.

The correct expressions that would return 2 and 1 results, for example, would be

```
[0-9]+/[0-9]+
```

and

```
[0-9]+/[0-9]+/
```

respectively. The `+` is known as a *quantifier*.

Comment: Actually, to precisely reflect OP's attempts at regex, you should use `[0-9]{1,4}/[0-9]{1,4}` instead of `[0-9]+/[0-9]+` you're suggesting. It seems he meant a four digit number as his maximum, while `[0-9]+` matches strings with any number of digits.

Comment: @Zaroth - True, thanks. I'll let your comment suffice, as I don't want to overcomplicate the answer, as OP seems new to any quantifiers at all.